# Use a hash to map to element id's with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form where I want to put previously submitted data into the correct form inputs. I have a hash where the keys are an id selector of the form input and the value is the the value for that specific form input.

This is what my hash looks like:

```
@saved_answers = {"123456"=>"Tom", "2345678"=>"Brady", "789456"=>"Football"}
```

I am passing this hash to be used in jQuery with

```
# found in the view's script
var form_saved_answers = '<%= @saved_answers.to_json %>';
```

Now when I am in the javascript file, I want to find an input id with the key and place the value in the input field.

This is where I am stuck, I've thought about making each key/value pair an array and run an each function... but there has to be a more direct approach...

Any ideas?

Comment: To clarify, you want to avoid http://paste.ofcode.org/iVC7dWzFyFtzz8V5keAGAk?

Comment: Is this a text or select input field that you are trying to create? In other words, do you need to display all the values in a dropdown, or just fill out a text field with the one value?

Comment: @JakeShorty I think this is going to be my biggest problem... the form has text_fields, selects and radios.... I guess for this question though... I'm more so just curious how you could do it with a text_field and then worry about the radio and select fields later.

Answer (score 0):

do it without `'` char `var form_saved_answers = <%= @saved_answers.to_json %>;`
now you can do `form_saved_answers['123456']` if key is not a number you can `form_saved_answers.some_key`

Answer (score 0):

Try this in js file..

```
var parsed_json = JSON.parse(form_saved_answers);
var val_of_key = parsed_json[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the hash parsed into JSON, you can key into the JSON object and pass that as the `value` attribute to a form input. As lisukorin said, if you set `form_saved_answers` to the result of the ERB *without* the quotes, you can then use that JSON like so in an input:

`myInput = '<input type="text" value="' + form_saved_answers[12345] +'">'`

That would give you a basic version of the HTML element with the value you want, to be manipulated as you need with jQuery.